# How to sort a php array by column(s) in one line of code

Tags: php

eg to how to sort by 'grade'

```
array
{
   array
   {
      'name' => 'name1',
      'price' => '100',
      'grade' => '4.4'
   },
   array
   {
      'name' => 'name16',
      'price' => '12',
      'grade' => '1.2'
   },
   array
   {
      'name' => 'name3',
      'price' => '143',
      'grade' => '2.4'
   }
}
```

This is similar to a locked question but I'd like to post a one-liner answer for review.
[How to Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/3859027. it is already tackled on this answer, the last one

Answer (score 0):

a one-liner:

```
array_multisort(array_column($myArray, 'grade'), SORT_ASC, $myArray);
```

`array_column` extracts a column

`array_multisort` sorts by one or more other arrays (the last parameter is the array to sort)

sort by more columns as needed, eg `grade` ascending, then `price` descending:

```
array_multisort(array_column($myArray, 'grade'), SORT_ASC, array_column($myArray, 'price'), SORT_DESC, $myArray);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort